# zypper - is there an option like --allowerasing for yum?

Tags: sles, zypper

I am asking to install a package `B` that is replacing (**and** conflicting with) another package `A`. In order to do it without user input, in `yum`  I use `--allowerasing`. Is there an option like that for `zypper`? The user is getting this message from `zypper`:

```
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: the to be installed B-some-version.x86_64 conflicts with 'A' provided by the installed A-some-other-version.x86_64
 Solution 1: deinstallation of A-some-other-version.x86_64
 Solution 2: do not install B-some-version.x86_64

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c/d/?] (c):
```

I tried with `--force`  which made no difference and I want it to go with option `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently these two options work together so that there's no user input requested:

```
zypper install --force-resolution -y package_name
```

The `-y` (or `--no-confirm`) enables non interactive mode, answering "yes" to every prompt. The `--force-resolution` (or `-R`) tells `zypper` to automatically make a choice to resolve questions.

Take that with a grain of salt... It works for my specific packages considering their dependencies/conflicts, but it might work differently in other scenarios.